# How to create a new list of tuples based on a values from original list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

My function is currently returning:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'e', 'f'), ('h', 'b', 'c')]
```

However, I need the final output to be:

```
[('a', 'h'), ('d', 'g')]
```

As you can see, if i[1] and i[2] match I need i[0] to be paired together.

I was trying to use a for loop but I can't think of how to write it, at this moment.

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: which requires sorted inputs

Comment: ....sort them first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'e', 'f'), ('h', 'b', 'c')]
print([(a[0], b[0]) for a, b in combinations(l, 2) if a[1:] == b[1:]])
```

Answer (score 1):

group based on the second and third elements of each tuple, appending the first element to a list then filter out the lists that have a length  < 1:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for a,b,c in l:
    d[b,c].append(a)

print([tuple(val) for val in d.values() if len(val)>1])
[('a', 'h'), ('d', 'g')]
```

To guarantee first match order use an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
for a,b,c in l:
    d.setdefault((b,c),[]).append(a)

print([tuple(val) for val in d.values() if len(val)>1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by sorting the list based on second and third element , and then using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) . Then for each group, you can take the first elements from the elements inside it. Example -

```
>>> a = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'e', 'f'), ('h', 'b', 'c')]
>>> lst = []
>>> new_a = sorted(a, key=lambda i: (i[1], i[2]))
>>> for _, x in itertools.groupby(new_a, lambda i: (i[1], i[2])):
...     lst.append(tuple(y[0] for y in x))
...
>>> lst
[('a', 'h'), ('d', 'g')]
```

---

This can also be done in one line as (though unreadable) -

```
>>> l = [tuple(y[0] for y in x) for _, x in itertools.groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda i: (i[1], i[2])), lambda i: (i[1], i[2]))]
>>> l
[('a', 'h'), ('d', 'g')]
```

Comment: unnecessary `n log n` sort

Comment: unnecessary when you can group using a dict

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution will preserve order (based on initial match location):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

x = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'e', 'f'), ('h', 'b', 'c')]
groupings, seen_list=defaultdict(list), []

for key, value in groupby(x, itemgetter(1, 2)):
    if key not in seen_list:
         seen_list.append(key)
    groupings[key].extend(list(map(itemgetter(0),value)))

print([groupings[key] for key in seen_list])
```

if order is not important you can disregard the seen_list and just print the groupings.values()

```
x = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'e', 'f'), ('h', 'b', 'c')]
groupings=defaultdict(list)
for key, value in groupby(x, itemgetter(1, 2)):
    groupings[key].extend(list(map(itemgetter(0),value)))

print(groupings.values())
```

Comment: you could just do this right `print groupings.values()`

Comment: sure assuming order is not important (unspecified :P)

Comment: Then you ca give the answer in two split one with  `seen_list` and another one without it and by the the way nice answer am the one who upvoted :)

Comment: Order does not matter - as long as the matched pairs are together

Answer (score 0):

May be not so pythonic, but a bit easier:

```
>>> a = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'e', 'f'), ('h', 'b', 'c')]    
>>> c = {}
>>> [c[j+k].append(i) if j+k in c else c.update({j+k:[i]}) for i,j,k in a]
>>> c = c.values()
>>> print c
[['d', 'g'], ['a', 'h']]
```